# How can I peek at intermediary files processed by asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I've got *somefile.js.coffee.erb* file which is processed by Rails asset pipeline. My ERB code  returns some string that cannot be parsed by Coffee which result in SyntaxError exception. I would like to peek into generated *somefile.js.coffee* file, or in general any intermediary file processed by asset pipeline.

I've tried to examine Sprockets with no luck:

```
environment = Sprockets::Environment.new
MyApplication::Application.config.assets.paths.each {|p| environment.append_path p}
rerb = environment['somefile.js.coffee.erb']
rerb.source #=> it's already preprocessed
```

Or to look into *\tmp\cache\assets* but there are also only preprocessed files, additionaly obscured by fingerprinted name.

Maybe there is a way to hook into asset-pipeline I have no idea how..

Why I need ERB? To generate client-side-model stubs with fields and validations matching Rails model using KnockoutJS (https://github.com/dnagir/knockout-rails extended -> https://github.com/KrzysztofMadejski/knockout-rails).

I am using Rails '~> 3.2.12', sprockets (2.2.2).

**Edit**: I've ended up injecting erb code in ### comments, to sneak-peak at generated code while coffeescript file is still compiling:

```
###
<%= somefun() %>
###
```

Altough I would suggest using @Semyon Perepelitsa answer as it produces coffee script file as it is seen by coffee compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove "coffee" from the file extension temporarily: somefile.js.erb. You will see its intermediate state at /assets/somefile.js as it won't be processed by CoffeeScript.

Comment: The simpler answer the better! Thank you. 

I've ended myself using hard-comments ### and putting ERB code inside, but this is even better as it produces whole file, as it will be seen by coffee compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you can put `<% binding.pry %>` just before the line and mess around till you get it right. Never tried during a compile and don't use coffeescript. In theory, it should work (or is worth a shot) so long as you put `gem pry` in your Gemfile and run `bundle` first.